# Hosted WCF service inside MVC Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, https

I added a WCF service in an existing MVC web application for showing it on the OLAP cube tool ([Syncfusion](http://help.syncfusion.com/js/olapclient/data-binding#wcf)). What happens when i execute the application with http enabled site, I am able to access the WCF method like below,

**Code**

```
$("#OlapClient").ejOlapClient({ url: "/Areas/OLAP/wcf/OlapClientService.svc"});
```

But when I do it from `https` enabled site I am not able to access the WCF method. It simply throws `404 method not found exception`. Here is the below web.config for my WCF.

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="OLAP.wcf.OlapClientServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>

  <service name="OLAP.wcf.OlapClientService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="OLAP.wcf.OlapClientServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="OLAP.wcf.IOlapClientService">

    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:15415/VibrantWS.svc/soap"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: does your website has valid https certificate ?

Comment: Yes, my whole application works except Olap cube tool which uses the wcf method.

Comment: Maybe you should play with WCF binding's security configuration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you working on .Net Frame work 4.5 advanced service, please the ensure IIS configuration under  “.Net Frame work 4.5 advanced service   WCF Serivce options  HTTP Activation (need to be checked)” .
2. Ensure the following settings in web.config as mention in below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx

[Enable SSL for my WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service)

[HTTPS-enabled, IIS hosted WCF service, How to secure it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849998/https-enabled-iis-hosted-wcf-service-how-to-secure-it)

3. Try the WEB API controller instead of WCF Service to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I started using WebAPI then it works like a charm without any hussle bustle of config settings as like WCF.

Comment: Thanks, save my day!